# From within Javascript (without JQuery), can I find if a function exists, that has a particular name?

Tags: javascript, function

From within Javascript (without JQuery), I need to find if a function with a particular name exists.

I want to "replace" a function as described here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3306973/606539). So, it would look something like this:

```
var fx='aFunctionName';
window['_o_'+fx]=window[fx];
window[fx]=function(){
  // do-whatever here
}
```

As best I can tell, in this example, it essentially renames a function named: `'aFunctionName'` to a new name: `'_o_aFunctionName'`, then creates a new function with the original name: `'aFunctionName'`.

In my testing so far, this is working perfectly.

But, I want to add some code that will do some checking first, before performing these operations:

1. Check to make sure the function named `'aFunctionName'` (`var fx`) exists.
2. Check to make sure a function named `'_o_aFunctionName'` (`['_o_'+fx]`) ***does not*** exist.

Comment: `typeof window[fx] === 'function'` and `typeof window['_o_'+fx] !== 'function'`?

Comment: Yes, you can use typeof to check if function is undefined

Comment: just to clarify - you are going to add the upvoted comments' typeof in some sort of logic statement (most likely an if).

Comment: @FelixKling - **`"typeof window[fx] ===..."`** this works great, on both IE9, and FF22. If you make an answer with this info, I'll mark it as the "accepted answer". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you want to test global functions, you can use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to find out what type the value is. Example:

```
typeof window[fx] === 'function'
// and
typeof window['_o_'+fx] !== 'function'
```

However, there is no way to test whether a *local* variable with a specific name exists (and what value it has).